# rest service with method post in visual studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rest

help please, I need to create a rest service in visual studio 2008 with the POST method, with JSON inputs and outputs, review tutorials but they do not work for me.

Comment: This is way too broad for Stack Overflow...

Comment: This is a very broad question and there are plenty of available resources to walk through to do such a thing.

Comment: Specifically I want to use c # that uses the POST method, which allows me to send data in JSON format, and the return is JSON, the problem is that if or if I should work in the 2008 version

Comment: Any reason you cant use VS2017 community edition? It is free.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple way :

```
        String fullUrl = "http://...";
        String jsonStringContent = "{...}";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fullUrl);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/json";
        // content
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonStringContent);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        Stream dataStream = req.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        //Response
        HttpWebResponse webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        reader = new StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream());
        String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
```